# Using Amazon G2 Instance to advance dedicated server for GPU tasks

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I recently learned about using Amazon's G2 instances to perform calculations for game development (e.g. lightmass calculation) according to this tutorial: http://gofreak.tumblr.com/post/87018936015/unreal-engine-4-developing-in-the-cloud

I was wondering if it would be possible to get a Spot instance of a g2.2xlarge, install all tools required (Visual Studio, the engine itself etc.), use the instance for performing GPU tasks and then save the instance (or just the storage used by the engine, where all files are etc. (like EBS, which I am unable to claim since I can not find an option to create a volume)) on my server.

So, my questions are:

- Can I store files on my Windows server and use these files in a spot instance when required?
- Is it possible to save a "clone" of the spot instance on my server (or on Amazon, depending on price) to be re-used with another spot instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you stop the instance, instead of terminating it, all the files within instance would be saved. Regardless of the instance type. While instance is stopped you would still be paying for storage, but that's a tiny fraction of the cost, comparing to the cost of actually running the instance.

To "save a clone" You can do a storage snapshot or create your own AMI image, so data you created can be reused.

You might also consider automating the provisioning of the instance, so it would automatically install and configure all the software required within the instance, so you can repeatedly recreate to instance configuration you need without storing images/snapshots.

Comment: When I look for the costs of the storage to hold the stopped spot instance, where would I look?

Comment: EC2 pricing is here: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/ Look at the Amazon Elastic Block Store. As of today it's $0.10 per GB-month of provisioned storage. So with 60GB default storage you are looking at extra $6/month on your bill.

Comment: Is it possible to use my own storage (Windows server at OVH) instead of EBS?

Comment: You can import/export images, but to run them they have to be moved to AWS. Check http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instances_of_your_vm.html there would be additional costs associated with moving data to/from AWS

Comment: This answer makes one important claim, in the context of this question, that is not correct.  Spot instances, unlike on-demand instances, **can't be stopped**.  [*"Note that you can't stop and start an Amazon EBS-backed instance if it is a Spot instance, but you can reboot or terminate it."*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/how-spot-instances-work.html).

Comment: Good point Michael. I missed the "spot" part here. There are still ways to preserve the work done on spot instance such as uncheck "Delete on Termination" for the root device and others, but I'm not familiar with Unreal Engine to make a call on if and how it would tolerate the instance interruption.